# Galois group of CM fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

I am looking for examples of CM fields whose Galois group is not abelian. By a **CM field** $K$ I mean a totally imaginary quadratic extension of a totally real field $K_0$. If the extension is not Galois I take the Galois closure.

Obviously the degree of such a field is even.

When $[K: \mathbb{Q}]=2$, $K$ is an imaginary quadratic field, so its Galois group is $\mathbb{Z}/2$.

My question is: what are the possible Galois groups for $[K: \mathbb{Q}]=4$ and 6?

For instance, if I consider $K=K_0(\xi_3)$, with $K_0$ totally real of degree 4 and $\xi_3$ the roots of unity of order $3$, what are the possible Galois groups?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You have to open *and close* equation with the $ sign in order for them to appear nice...

Comment: Sorry for the mistake

Comment: well for any galois extension $K$, with $[K/\mathbb{Q}]=4$ the possible galois groups are $V4$ or $\mathbb{Z}/2$, so neither will be non-abelian.

Comment: But there is no reason for the extension to be Galois